# Use WordPress and ASP.NET Framework together inside a server

Tags: asp.net, wordpress

My partner and I are working on a project together.

My part was mostly using WordPress. The design and all is finished, you can view the link here;
[this is temporary hosting](http://trigonometee.com/fuen/)

While my partner is working on the dynamic part, where the user can input information, calling the database, etc. And she's decided to use the ASP.NET framework as she is fluent in that.

If you notice my static WordPress site, there is one button on the banner called 'START ORDERING'. This button supposedly brings in the user into the dynamic page, which now she did offsite using ASP.NET Framework (Visual Studio Community)

I've done enough research and still couldn't figure out how and what is the step in order to achieve this. Highly appreciate your help.

Comment: that will depend on your webserver. Are you using IIS?

Comment: The current temporary server is using Linux. Do we have to use Windows Web Hosting to test this out?

Comment: No, but you are limited to `.net core` on linux. To run asp.net on linux takes some work setting up proxies.

Comment: might be easiest to just host it on separate servers and link from the wordpress site to the asp.net site

Comment: What if I use entirely Windows? My plan is to get the Windows Hosting Server, then install my WordPress. Next, I will create a new folder within the file manager, and deploy my asp.net inside this new folder. Would it work?

Comment: It's all about configuring the webserver. With the right IIS settings it would work.

Comment: Is it like a Try and Error thing or does it have a manual to configure the Webserver and IIS settings?

Comment: it's really wrong site for that kind of question. maybe superuser.com

Comment: Really sorry about that as I am really not that fluent in this. Thank you for your comments and views.